# Post navigation for custom post loop not working

Tags: php, wordpress

i have create custom loop for posts on my custom template, but i want to use the post numbers to form a set of post pagination links.

pagination has not worked in my custom loop. How can i do it, where i must use pagination function, what is the name of the pagination function? , thank you?

```
<?php

// Template Name: Blog

get_header(); ?>


    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <section id="main" class="site-main blog" role="main">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-12">    

                              <?php $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'post'
                                );
                                $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
                                if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
                                  while($post_query->have_posts() ) {

                                        $post_query->the_post(); ?>

                                        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content-blog', 'none'); ?>    

                                    <?php  

                                      }

                                    } ?>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-12">

                                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'blog_sidebar' ); ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </section><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: Corrected poor english to add spport for understanding what the question is trying to ask.

Comment: @aleks-pnv - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops check this article it may help you

Comment: you need to set paged variable to query and if you want to set custom pagination then check https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154360/pagination-custom-query